# TypeError: o.registerevents not a function

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

how to solve this error after publish angular6 build on IIS any idea

[image]

Comment: Some code will be helpful :)

Comment: what kind of code ..? build successfully publish console log shows api is calling but page does not show

Comment: Please provide the code so it can be looked at and that way the community can start providing help and support. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

i am using syncfusion Angular Controls that's why its show me Error, comment `<ejs-dialog>` its working fine